# Can there be no outliers as per calculation with IQR formula while the boxplot shows there are outliers in the dataset?

Tags: outliers, boxplot

While plotting a box plot, the plot is showing the columns in the dataset has outliers, but while trying to calculate it by IQR formula, it is showing there are 0 outliers in the columns of the dataset, why is it showing this? How to find the outliers that the boxplot is showing?[image]

Comment: I don't know Python, but it looks like your formula is operating on the whole data set, while the graph is divided by category.